# Entity Framework Join inner Include

Tags: entity-framework, join, include

What is wrong ?

```
var tests = _repo.Tests.Include(a => a.Answers.Join(_repo.Questions, answer => answer.QuestionNumber, question => question.QuestionNumber, (answer, question) => new { Answer = answer, Question = question })).Where(u => u.User.UserName == username);
```

error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Join(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func, Func, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: The compiler probably tried to tell you with an exception. If there was no exception and you're just not seeing what you think you should see, well, you tell us what is wrong.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThenInclude to join the other tables like this.

```
var tests = _repo.Tests
    .Include(a => a.Answers)
      .ThenInclude(q => q.Questions)
    .Where(u => u.User.UserName == username)
    .ToList();
```